# Adding a "Submit" button to a form

Tags: php, html, form-submit

I am trying to add in a "submit" button into this form:

```
<div class="wptrigger_content">
<input type="text" class="wptgg_pass_key wptrigger" />
<input type="hidden" onclick="function(".wptgg_pass_key")" value="?">
<span class="wptgg_action">&nbsp;</span>
<input type="hidden" class = "wptgg_id" value="<?php echo $param['id'] ;?>" />
<div class="wptrigger_append"></div>
</div>
```

At the moment, you have to use a keyboard to process the request - but this doesn't work on Android devices as the "Next" button leads to a dead end and no processing of the function. I tried changing "hidden" to "submit" but no luck.

I tried changing "hidden" to "submit" but no luck.

Comment: It sounds like your question is HTML (not necessarily PHP, and certainly not Android).  An HTML "submit" button is easy: [<input type="submit">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit).  It "submits" an HTML form.  Q: Where's your form?  SUGGESTION: work through some "HTML forms 101" tutorials, e.g.: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: There is no `<form>` element in that "form".

Comment: *"but this doesn't work on Android devices as the "Next" button leads to a dead end"* - i think we miss something big. something important you haven't told us. is it really only involves [tag:php] and [tag:html]?

Comment: All of your inputs are missing the `name` attribute which is required for form elements that aren't being processed with javascript

Comment: So Zak: please look at the tutorial I linked to above, [HTML Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).  Copy/paste the code, try it out. 
 Ask any questions you have about it.  Notice how a "submit" sends the completed "form" back from the browser to the "server".  Then apply those concepts to *your* application.